# Bootstrap - Fixed collapssible navbar button without the rest of the bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a responsive drag and drop game using Bootstrap and jQuery UI.

I am using Bootstrap collapsible navbar at the top of the page and would like to hide the navbar and leave only the toggle button fixed at the corner of the screen to save some space to the buttons at the bottom.

A screenshot of the page:

[image]

I can't set the navbar to be fixed and transparent because I need the polygon behind it to receive a dropped element.

I also don't want to allow scrolling because that would interfere with the drag and drop.

Here is my code:

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Connaissez vous Sain<i Style="color: #B34; font-size: 28px" class="fa fa-map-signs" aria-hidden="true"></i>é ?</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li ><a href="index.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"
                     aria-hidden="true"></span> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="aboutus.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> About</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                     role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>
                     Menu <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="quartiers.php">Noms des Quartiers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Centres des Quartiers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Points d'interets</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Land Marks</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</nav>
```

**Update:**

I figured out a simple solution using css:

```
    nav {
        position: fixed;
        top: -60px;
    }

    .navbar-toggle {
        position: relative;
        top: 60px;
        z-index: 10;
    }
```

Screenshot of the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
/* @Media query for mobile only maybe needed here */
.navbar-brand{
  display: none;
}
.navbar{
  float: right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><i Style="color: #B34; font-size: 28px" class="fa fa-map-signs" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li ><a href="index.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"
                     aria-hidden="true"></span> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="aboutus.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> About</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                     role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>
                     Menu <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="quartiers.php">Noms des Quartiers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Centres des Quartiers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Points d'interets</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Land Marks</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</nav>

<script>

$( ".navbar-toggle" ).click(function() {
  if($( "#navbar" ).hasClass( "in" )){
    $('.navbar').css('float','right');
  }else{
    $('.navbar').css('float','none');
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```